# Add an ROC column to multiple xts files in r

Tags: r, function, xts

I have several `xts` object with stock market data. I am trying to add the Rate of Change (ROC) from the `TTR` package, but want to write a function to do that.

It works the "verbose" way, but somehow the function does not do the trick:

```r
#Loading the data
library(xts)
library(quantmod)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyquant)
library(Hmisc)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(TTR)

StartDate <- "2017-01-01"

# Get data from yahoo finance

symbolsYahoo <- c("^FTSE", "^GDAXI")

loadSymbols(Symbols = symbolsYahoo, from = StartDate, periodicity = "daily" )


#verbose way
GDAXI$GDAXI.ROC <- na.locf(ROC(Cl(GDAXI)))

#function
rocFun <- function(x){
  x <- merge(x, na.locf(ROC(Cl(x))))
}

rocFun(GDAXI)
```

I have tried several other ways of writing that function but none add the column.
Can you help?

Comment: What does `Cl` do?

Comment: @Gautam Cl makes sure that the Rate of Change is calculated on the closing prices.

Comment: If `GDAXI$GDAXI.ROC <- na.locf(ROC(Cl(GDAXI)))` works, I would expect `rocFun <- function(x){
  x$ROC <-  na.locf(ROC(Cl(x))); return(x)
}` to work.

Comment: @Gregor I thought so as well, and return(x) also outputs the data in the console, but when I view the xts object afterwards the column is missing

Comment: Just like any other R function, you need to assign the result to modify the object. If you have `x = 1`, then `x + 2` will print `3`, but `x` is still 1. If you want to modify `x`, you do `x = x + 2`, and now `x` is 3. If you want to modify your `GDAXI` object, `GDAXI = rocFun(GDAXI)`.

Comment: @Gregor That makes sense. But I have a total of 25 xts and wanted to do this via apply() over all the 25 xts objects and not having to write out the specific names, as chances are, that there will be more and more objects. I Thought with the ```x$ROC <- na.locf(ROC(Cl(x)))``` I do the assignement within the function.

Comment: @Gregor with the assignement call it works. Now I just have to get this assignment call into the fucntion as well. Thank you for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: No! Don't make a function that modifies something without assignment. That's weird and bad - it is unexpected, can cause hard-to-find bugs, and isn't like anything else in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing much about `xts` objects, here's a hacky way of doing this. I'm sure there are more elegant ways to achieve this:

```
library(xts)

GDAXI <- sample.xts

func1 <- function(df){
  k <- as.data.frame(z)
  k$ROC <- ROC(k$Close)
  return(k)
}

func2 <- function(xts_object, col = 4){
  names_initial <- names(xts_object)
  k <- ROC(xts_object[, col])
  ret <- merge(xts_object, k)
  names_new <- c(names_initial, 'ROC')
  names(ret) <- names_new
  return(ret)
}
```

`func1` converts the `xts` object to a `data.frame` and adds a column, whereas `func2` uses `merge` to add an `ROC` column without changing the class. The output is below:

```
> str(func1(GDAXI))
'data.frame':   180 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Open : num  50 50.2 50.4 50.4 50.2 ...
 $ High : num  50.1 50.4 50.4 50.4 50.2 ...
 $ Low  : num  50 50.2 50.3 50.2 50.1 ...
 $ Close: num  50.1 50.4 50.3 50.3 50.2 ...
 $ ROC  : num  NA 5.57e-03 -1.30e-03 4.45e-05 -3.05e-03 ...

> str(func2(GDAXI))
An ‘xts’ object on 2007-01-02/2007-06-30 containing:
  Data: num [1:180, 1:5] 50 50.2 50.4 50.4 50.2 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:5] "Open" "High" "Low" "Close" ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: 
  xts Attributes:  
List of 1
 $ descr: chr "my new xts object"

> head(func2(GDAXI))
               Open     High      Low    Close           ROC
2007-01-02 50.03978 50.11778 49.95041 50.11778            NA
2007-01-03 50.23050 50.42188 50.23050 50.39767  5.569091e-03
2007-01-04 50.42096 50.42096 50.26414 50.33236 -1.296719e-03
2007-01-05 50.37347 50.37347 50.22103 50.33459  4.445937e-05
2007-01-06 50.24433 50.24433 50.11121 50.18112 -3.053731e-03
2007-01-07 50.13211 50.21561 49.99185 49.99185 -3.778799e-03
```

You could loop through the vector of your stock names using `lapply('GDAXI', function(z){...})` instead of passing individual `xts` objects.

Comment: Thank you. will try that out.

Comment: Yes, it did work. Thank you. And sorry it took so long.